# How to store signed 16bit value in pymodbus register

Tags: python, python-2.7, modbus

I am trying to implement a pymodbus server. I am using ModbusSparseDataBlocks in the ModbusSlaveContext. This works so far. The client can write and read vales from every register instantiated.

But I have problems with negative values. The client needs 16bit signed integer format and he can not interpret my negative values.

This is how I fill the register with values:

```
#write positive value (100) to IR[0x10] --> client interprets this correctly
context[0x00].setValues(4, 0x10, 100)
#write negative value (-100) to IR[0x10] --> client can't read this, throws failure
context[0x00].setValues(4, 0x10, -100)
```

How can I write a valid 16bit signed integer to the register?

(I am using python 2.7 and pymodbus version 1.2.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your library only understands unsigned 16-bit numbers.  If you bitwise-AND the signed value with 0xFFFF (a 16-bit mask) in Python, you'll get the same result:

What you're doing:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('<H',struct.pack('<h',-100))[0]
65436
```

Bitwise-AND:

```
>>> -100 & 0xFFFF
65436
```

So you can do:

```
context[0x00].setValues(4, 0x10, -100 & 0xFFFF)
```

Positive values will be unaffected, and negative values result in the unsigned 16-bit 2's complement value.

To convert an unsigned 2's complement 16-bit value back to signed, test for the sign bit (2<sup>15</sup>) and subtract 2<sup>16</sup> if present:

```
value = value-2**16 if value & 2**15 else value
```

or equivalently:

```
value = value-0x10000 if value & 0x8000 else value
```

Comment: Thank you, a really nice solution. Could you please also post a way to convert this signed 16bit integer back to a valid python integer?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that following works for me, but I don't know if this is the correct and safe way.

```
import struct

def signed(value):
    packval = struct.pack('<h',value)
    return struct.unpack('<H',packval)[0]

#write positive value (100) to IR[0x10] --> client interprets this correctly
context[0x00].setValues(4, 0x10, signed(100))
#write negative value (-100) to IR[0x10] --> client interprets this correctly
context[0x00].setValues(4, 0x10, signed(-100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply calculate it manually:

```
if value < 0:
    value = 2**16 + value
context[0x00].setValues(4, 0x10, signed(value))
```

Comment: Your solution seems to provide wrong value. If I use your solution for the value `-100` I get the value `65636` which equals `0b0001 0000 0000 0110 0100`. (The low order 16bits do no represent a negative number.)

Comment: Yes, because the "-" in the second line was wrong. I fixed this in the example. Now it is working for values within this range [2**15, 2**15-1]